# Check whether element of table is the same as column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
data <- tibble(
  product_01 = c("AB", "AC", NA),
  product_02 = c("AD", NA, "AB"),
  AB = NA,
  AC = NA,
  AD = NA)
```

Now, I want to get the following tibble:

```
> data
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  product_01 product_02 AB    AC    AD   
  <chr>      <chr>      <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 AB         AD         TRUE  FALSE TRUE   
2 AC         NA         FALSE TRUE  FALSE   
3 NA         AB         TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

i.e. for each element of a row (in columns starting with product) check whether that element is the same as the name of the column (after columns starting with product) and put `TRUE` if the same and `FALSE` otherwise. Does someone have any idea how to proceed here? I tried some code (mostly with `lapply`) but with no results. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
cols <- names(data)[-(1:2)]
data[cols] <- t(apply(data[1:2], 1, function(x)  cols %in% x))

# product_01 product_02    AB    AC    AD   
#  <chr>      <chr>      <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 AB         AD         TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#2 AC         NA         FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#3 NA         AB         TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

---

I think in general case, we would not have already created columns with `NA` values.

```
data <- tibble(
  product_01 = c("AB", "AC", NA),
  product_02 = c("AD", NA, "AB"))
```

We can then use `dplyr` and `tidyr` in the following way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 <- data %>% mutate(row = row_number())

data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row,
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = val, values_fill = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(data1, by = 'row')
```

Comment: Hey Ronak thanks :). Do you think there is a dplyr solution for this problem?

Comment: It is not a one-liner but I updated the answer with a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution. @danish

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` try that will work but I am not that comfortable in using loops, that's why it is a bit long

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>% mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-AB, -AC, -AD) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(product_01, product_02), names_to ='name', values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  mutate(val2 = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row_id, names_from = val, 
values_from = val2, values_fill =FALSE) 

data %<>% mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-AB, -AC, -AD) %>%
  left_join(data2, by = "row_id") %>%
  select(-row_id)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  product_01 product_02 AB    AD    AC   
  <chr>      <chr>      <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 AB         AD         TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
2 AC         NA         FALSE FALSE TRUE 
3 NA         AB         TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I just noticed that Ronak has also given a solution on similar lines in a better way.  :)